# Writing Corda custom query by concating two schema column values and compare?

Tags: corda

We have Name schema contains,

- FirstName : Rock
- LastName : John
- Prefix : Mr
- MiddleName : ""
- Suffix: "Jr"

We are creating some states, schema with the definition.

But Now Want to field the states with values. We need to filter the values like
**(FirstName+LastName).equals("RockJohn").**

We are trying to write the custom vault query.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you'd write something like:

```
FieldInfo firstNameField = getField("firstName", NameSchemaV1.PersistentName.class);
FieldInfo lastNameField = getField("lastName", NameSchemaV1.PersistentName.class);

CriteriaExpression firstNameIndex = Builder.equal(firstNameField, "Rock");
CriteriaExpression lastNameIndex = Builder.equal(lastNameField, "John");

QueryCriteria firstNameCriteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(firstNameIndex);
QueryCriteria lastNameCriteria = new QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(lastNameIndex);

QueryCriteria criteria = firstNameCriteria.and(lastNameCriteria);
Vault.Page<ContractState> results = getServiceHub().getVaultService().queryBy(NameState.class, criteria);
```

In Kotlin, you'd write something like:

```
val results = builder {
    val firstNameIndex = NameSchemaV1.PersistentName::firstName.equal("Rock")
    val lastNameIndex = NameSchemaV1.PersistentName::lastName.equal("John")

    val firstNameCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(firstNameIndex)
    val lastNameCriteria = QueryCriteria.VaultCustomQueryCriteria(lastNameIndex)

    val criteria = firstNameCriteria.and(lastNameCriteria)
    serviceHub.vaultService.queryBy(NameState::class.java, criteria)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Joel. But we will be receiving the fullName as argument like "RockJohn". We need filter by combining the two values and compare with "RockJohn"

Comment: Then how about adding a `FullName` field to the schema?

Comment: Thanks, @Joel. But it goes against our data model so we need this kind of format search.

Comment: I don't believe that kind of query is possible currently, no.

Comment: Thanks. I suggested your recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [Hibernate formula](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Formula.html) to create a dynamic/calculated property:

```
@Formula(value = " concat(first_name, last_name) ")
String fullName
```

Then treat it as a regular property/field in your queries